# How to make an operator animatable, even with a workaround

Tags: python, animation, operator

I've some operators that will appear like buttons in the UI. I want to give the user the possibility to add keyframe to the operators.

[image]

Looking in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator#bpy.types.Operator) it doesn't seem to be possible.
Is there an easy way to do it? Or can I try some workaround?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Operators are tools to change data they aren't animatable, unlike properties. They are functions you run instantaneously, you can't put keyframes on them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For example I have one operator that toggle viewport visibility for a group of item (mixed between objects and modifiers). 
I could use a simple Boolean Property but I can't figure out how to perform different operations if the user click on the property.

Comment: Then you should probably be looking for a way to easily keyframe multiple different properties at wonce

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Duarte Farrajota Ramos it is not possible to animate operators.
I solved using a BoolProperty in the UI instead of an operator. Thanks to the 'update' function we can then specify the operation we need to perform.
Here is some example code.

```
class someClass(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

   def viewport_toggle(self, context):
    
      #do what you want


   visibility : BoolProperty (default=True, update =viewport_toggle)
```